# Is it possible to select items from IEnumerablle by two ids?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this piece of code that I usually use to update/delete/create items

```
HashSet<int> current = new HashSet<int>(diagram.Links.Select(lnk => lnk.IDInput);
HashSet<int> received = new HashSet<int>(d.Links.Select(lnk => lnk.IDInput));
IEnumerable<int> delete = current.Except(received);
IEnumerable<int> new = received.Except(current);
```

And it works perfect when my list works with one ID but it this case I want to do something like  `diagram.Links.Select(lnk => lnk.IDInput AND lnk.IDOutput)` Is it even possible or should I use Where instead?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look at `SelectMany`, or `Concat`.

Comment: Use `Tuple` as value for hashset. `var received= d.Links.Select(l => (l.IdInput, l.IdOutput)).ToHashSet();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose one of these 3 options

1. Create an anonymous object

   ```
    diagram.Links.Select(lnk => new {lnk.IDInput, lnk.IDOutput})
   ```
2. Create a value tuple

   ```
    diagram.Links.Select(lnk => (lnk.IDInput, lnk.IDOutput))
   ```
3. Use a Class / Struct

   ```
    public class IDHolder
    {
        public string IDInput;
        public string IDOutput;
    }

    diagram.Links.Select(lnk => new IDHolder() {IDInput = lnk.IDInput, IDOutput = lnk.IDOutput}))
   ```

All three would work, the latter is the most coherent in my taste, but choose whatever works best for you.

Comment: Yes, 1 and 2 are suitable solutions, but the terminology is wrong: 1 would be an *anonymous object* (not a Dynamic object) and 2 would be a *value tuple* (not a Touple object). Option 3 won't work as expected in a HashSet, since your class does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, so two objects with the same IDInput and IDOutput will be seen as different object. Both anonymous objects and ValueTuples automatically implement the required methods by combining their fields in a suiltable way.

Comment: I finally went with third option. I'll tried all and all worked but this was best option for me too

Comment: @Heinzi you are correct, will edit my answer with the valid terminology. Not sure how HashSet is relevant here though, the question is "Is it possible to select items from IEnumerable by two ids", and all three options accomplish that. He didn't ask for the result collection to be distinct.

Comment: @amitc: I have created an example to illustrate what I mean: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6jX3xC . Does that help?

Comment: @Heinzi understood that part, just did not see how it is related to the question.

Comment: @amitc: In their code example, OP creates two hash sets. Using solution 3, both of these hash sets will contain *different* IDHolder objects (albeit with the same content). Thus, `Enumerable.Except` (lines 3 and 4 of OP's example code) will see them as different objects (even if they have the same content) and will not do what OP expects.

Answer (score 1):

For not change the other logic in your code you can simply use `Concat` like this:

```
HashSet<int> current = new HashSet<int>(diagram.Links.Select(lnk => lnk.IDInput)
.Concat(diagram.Links.Select(lnk => lnk.IDOutput)));

HashSet<int> received = new HashSet<int>(d.Links.Select(lnk => lnk.IDInput)
.Concat(d.Links.Select(lnk => lnk.IDOutput)));
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally used another class to do it but this worked too